# PowerShell.exe arguments when running scripts

Tags: powershell, cmd

What is the difference between these two:

- cmd prompt:
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe **-File**
  MyScript.ps1 -JobName A,B,C
- powershell prompt: .\MyScript.ps1 -JobName A,B,C

In MyScript.ps1 I have a mandatory parameter of: [String[]] $JobName

For whatever reason, the cmd prompt won't run properly, unless I remove -File, while the PS prompt runs fine. I've always run PS scripts from the cmd prompt with the -File switch. Is there a way to include -File and still get it to work? Am I not quoting something properly? Does it matter if I don't include -File?

Comment: Try `-Command` instead  `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -Command ".\MyScript.ps1 -JobName A,B,C"`

Comment: The first advice I'd offer is that you get into the habit of double quoting your arguments, `"MyScript.ps1"` and `"A,B,C"`. If you decide to use the example in the comment above instead, then use single ones, `"'.\MyScript.ps1' -JobName 'A,B,C'"`, or escaped doubles, `"\".\MyScript.ps1\" -JobName \"A,B,C\""`.